# SQL PDW set multiple variables in SELECT

Tags: parallel-data-warehouse

I am working in SQL Parallel Data Warehouse / APS.  I am trying to set the values of multiple variables in a single SELECT statement.  My code is:

```
DECLARE
    @var1 int
    ,@var2 int
;
SELECT
    @var1 = col1
    ,@var2 = col2
FROM
    A
;
```

PDW is throwing the following error:

> Parse error ... Incorrect syntax near '='

Is this not valid syntax on PDW?  If not, how do I resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a restriction on how you assign variable values. Try this instead:

```
DECLARE
    @var1 int
    ,@var2 int
;
SET @var1 = (SELECT col1 FROM A);
SET @var2 = (SELECT col2 FROM A);
```